# how to find the other process

Tags: windows, debugging

Anyone know a tool I can use to debug "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" exceptions? I suspect a virus scanner but I can't be sure.

Comment: @skaffman has a crystal ball, or infers correctly from AV.

Comment: skaffman's crystal ball just knows Windows's error messages :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WhoLockMe](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) will tell you which process is keeping the file locked.

Answer (score 3):

Sysinternals [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) or [`Procmon`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) are the best tools for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution using MS sysinternals called handles:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx